# In driver.findElement(By.id("username").clear()); what is the use of "By"?

Tags: java, selenium

In `driver.findElement(By.id("username").clear());`

what is the use of "By" ?

Comment: its an query object. [`By`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/By.java) is the object name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"By"** is a class of **"org.openqa.selenium"** package. It is used to locate webelements from a webpage. The static methods, in it like: **"className, id, xpath, etc."**, can be accessed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

"By" defines the locating strategy to be used in identifying a web element on a page. In this case, the locating strategy here is "id". In another words, you are finding a webelement by id method or strategy